# Trying to set a cookie in Go, getting a CORS error stating Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not set to true

Tags: go, cookies, cross-domain

I'm trying to set a cookie in Go. When I run my code I get a CORS error in the browser stating Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to nothing and needs to be true. However, in my code it's set to true. Do you know what the issue might be?

### CORS Error

`Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

### Go code snippets

```
func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        return
    }
}
```

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

    header := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"})
    methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})
    origin := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"http://127.0.0.1:8080"})

r.HandleFunc("/signup", signup).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(header, methods, origin)(r)))
```

### Client side JS

```
fetch(`${URL_API}/signup`, {
        method: 'post',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
```

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are not the same host so it's treating it as a cross-origin request.

Comment: @Adrian Sorry both for now are 127.0.0.1 have updated the post. Still getting an error. Thanks!

Comment: In the same where you have your `handlers.AllowedOrigins(…)` call, have you tried adding `handlers.AllowCredentials(true)`? https://github.com/rs/cors#parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sideshowbarker was completely correct, thanks. I hadn't passed handlers.AllowCredentials() into handlers.CORS which resulted in the above error.

Fixed code :

```golang
creds := handlers.AllowCredentials()
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS(header, methods, origin, creds)(r)))
```